# Drop down menu loads all images?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

***FIXED***
*change #media a to #media > a, so it will select only the direct child and not all sub-children 
Thanks to Zoltan Toth*

I have made a drop down menu with HTML and CSS.
The text 'onze media' - 'adverteren' are actually images and no plain text.

At 'onze media' I've set some drop menu under 'onze media' but the 'onze media' image is loaded on every line. It's supposed to be only at the top, so the first main button needs to be 'onze media'

How to fix this?

***HTML***

```
<ul id="drop-down-menu">
  <li id="home"><a href=""></a></li> 
  <li id="media"><a href=""></a> 
    <ul>
      <li id="1a"><a href="">Blabla</a></li>
      <li id="1b"><a href="">Blabla Beauty</a></li> 
      <li id="1c"><a href="">Blabla Slijterij</a></li>
      <li id="1d"><a href="">Blabla</a></li>
      <li id="1e"><a href="">Blabla App</a></li> 
      <li id="1f"><a href="">Blabla.nl</a></li>
      <li id="1g"><a href="">Blabla.nl</a></li>
      <li id="1h"><a href="">Blabla.nl</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li id="ad"><a href=""></a></li>
  <li id="ons"><a href=""></a></li> 
  <li id="co"><a href=""></a></li> 
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
#drop-down-menu{
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
ul li{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  float:left
}
li ul{
  display:none
}
ul li a{
  display:block;
  margin-left:1px;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover{
  color:inherit;
}
li:hover ul{ 
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
}
li:hover li{ 
  font-size:70%;
  clear:left; 
  width:12em;
}
li:hover a{
  color:inherit;
}
li:hover li a:hover{
  color:inherit;
}
.clear_all{
  clear:both;
  height:0.5em;
}
#home a{
  height:55px;
  width:206px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/home_normal.png );
}   
#home a:hover{
  height:55px;
  width:206px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/home_selected.png );
}
#media a{
  height:49px;
  width:85px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/media_normal.png );
}   
#media a:hover{
  height:49px;
  width:85px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/media_selected.png );
}
#ad a{
  height:49px;
  width:90px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/ad_normal.png );
}   
#ad a:hover{
  height:49px;
  width:90px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/ad_selected.png );
}
#ons a{
  height:49px;
  width:69px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/over_normal.png );
}   
#ons a:hover{
  height:49px;
  width:69px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/over_selected.png );
}
#co a{
  height:49px;
  width:65px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/contact_normal.png );
}   
#co a:hover{
  height:49px;
  width:65px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image : URL(images/menu/contact_selected.png );
}
```

***Image***

[image]

**When changing #media a to #media > a the main image will be fixed but how do I change position and images of the sub links?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `#media a` and `#media a:hover` to `#media > a` and `#media > a:hover`, so it will select only the direct child and not all sub-children

```css
#media a{
  height:49px;
  width:85px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#media a:hover{
  height:49px;
  width:85px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#media > a{
  background-image : URL(images/menu/media_normal.png );
} 

#media > a:hover{
  background-image : URL(images/menu/media_selected.png );
}
```

Comment: Could you help with this next problem? I've edited my question at the bottom I've added a new image.

Comment: @F4LLCON, if you have a separate issue, you should post it as another question.

Comment: I've added the CSS - it should style ALL your `<a>`-s as before, but add the BG image only to the direct child

Comment: Hello thanks for this, I'll test it out on monday but I'm sure it works. I fixed it btw, it shows a white background with grey txt and red overlay with white txt on the childs.